# Why browsers do not save JWT token same way they save the cookie?

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, cookies, jwt

I know the differences between a cookie and a json web token. When the server sends set-cookie in its response header, browser automatically saves the cookie in local storage and whenever it is needed or making subsequent api calls, it gets automatically transmitted. But JWT tokens are sent in response body, we have to manually save it to the local storage and retrieve it manually and attach to request's header when making subsequent requests to the server.

Am I missing here something? I am just looking for a way to send the token to client in a best possible way, and want it be automatically saved and retrieved and then attached to the request just like cookie. Is there something like 'set-token' response header or can I simply transmit token in a cookie? I am a beginner and starting to learn.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: It’s your decision, whether to use Cookie or JWT for authentication, but natively the fact, you have to manage your JWT in on client yourself is one of the biggest differences. If you want it stored automatically, you have to look for a javascript-framework or anything else based on the technology you use that does it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies are meant to be used with a browser so if your application will always only support browser-based access then use cookies so they are easier to setup and use.

JWT is a more advanced solution used for API access and while it can also be used for a browser-based application, you need to do all the legwork as you already have seen.

Comment: Hi victor, thanks for the response. I was wondering if I could attach JWT token to the request header for every request so that I don't have to do it every time when I am making the request to the server?

Comment: Yes, depending upon your client-side Javascript library, you can setup a request interceptor that automatically sets the JWT token in the request header. e.g. https://www.tutorialdocs.com/article/axios-learn.html